# Average Wait Time or Times?

Tags: grammatical-number, time, uncountable-nouns

I can't figure out this sentence:

> We are experiencing longer than average wait times.

I checked the dictionary. Time should not be countable.

Can anyone tell me which one is correct?

> average wait times vs. average wait time
>
> wait times vs. wait time

Thanks!

Comment: Is this for a single line or multiple?  If all rides at Disney Land are taking longer, then “***times*** is appropriate.

Comment: Please specify which dictionary you checked. And then look in [some more](https://www.onelook.com/?w=time&ls=a).

Answer (score 1):

*We are experiencing longer than average wait times.*

Usage wise, Google has 126 returns for the above but none for the above using the singular *time*. (Yet the term *average wait time* has about five times the hits as *average wait times*.)

Are you speaking about a singular event or singular subject? Or plural? (Traveling together, we is treated as singular in re time/s.) Consider examples using *grade* instead of *time*:

- I received an above average grade in Physics. (this semester's grade)
- I received above average grades in Physics. (each test or semester)
- We received an above average grade on our Physics project (our
  project, thus we is singular)
- We received above average grades in Physics. (people in my study group, or multiple projects)